# Is there a way to create a registry SubKey and set it's value under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ ... \FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\

Tags: c#, registrykey

Is there a way to create a registry SubKey and set it's value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\` in C#

I've tried

```
using System.Security.Permissions; 

using Microsoft.Win32;

...

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyApp.exe", true);
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.SetValue(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyApp.exe", 11001);
```

but it creates the registry SubKey under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

I want to set the version of Internet Explorer used by the WPF WebBrowser Control and don't really know how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your key exists and if not create it

```
 var localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);
        var key = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

        var subKey = key.OpenSubKey("MyApp.exe", true);
        if (subKey == null)
        {
            subKey = key.CreateSubKey("MyApp.exe");                 
        }

        subKey.SetValue("MyApp.exe", 10001);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I've debugged the app and it did not have the required security permissions to access the LocalMachine registry hive so I've used CurrentUser instead and it works perfectly.